# Single-station FM radio

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation

I'd like to build an FM radio that is pre-tuned to a specific station. I could use something like the [Si4703 FM tuner chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12938), but they're expensive and difficult to solder by hand (and require a microcontroller).

If a normal FM receiver is tuned by a variable capacitor, is there a way to calculate a fixed value for that cap so that the radio would only be tuned to one frequency?

While there are several posts asking a similar question ([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/limit-a-radio-to-a-single-station), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218073/tuning-simplest-fm-to-93-5mhz)) none really offer an answer based in a circuit (and instead suggest hot gluing the tuner knob).

Comment: There is no practical way. Use a trimmer capacitor and leave it once tuned.

Comment: Capacitor still have tolerance nowadays, it will be a miracle if you have the correct frequency. As advice @BrianDrummond, use a variable capacitor, find the good frequency and leave it as it is

Comment: See: http://electronics-diy.com/fm-broadcast-receiver.php and http://electronics-diy.com/simple-fm-radio-receiver.php

Comment: Thanks @M.Ferru, that's what I feared. Do you know how the digital FM ICs do it? Some kind of feedback mechanism to see if the internal tuning cap is correct?

Comment: No I don't know anythings about these IC. However, I counld't find any chip working without a µC (with busses). Theses IC works with an internal oscillator that can change the frequency of the tuning cap. No capacitors needed.. 
If you find the IC, a formula will be provide in the datasheet

Comment: That link goes to a largely marketing splash page for a FM module, not a chip.  Provide a link *to the actual datasheet* of whatever it is you are referring to.

Comment: @JeffThompson: No on-board tuning cap.  The frequency is digitally derived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using an Arduino Nano and a [TEA5767 FM module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/253063859646?chn=ps&dispItem=1).

Very simple setup.  Very small size.

---

**Digital frequency accuracy and no drift.**

The software library supports presets and scanning functions if you want to add a few buttons and a few more lines of code.

Software details and download information is available here:

https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TEA5767Radio

**The single-station program is shown here:**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <TEA5767Radio.h>
TEA5767Radio radio = TEA5767Radio();
void setup() {  
  Wire.begin();
  radio.setFrequency(100.1); 
  }
void loop(){}
```

---

Since the program is stored in the Nano's EEPROM all it needs is power applied and it locks onto the station as soon as it boots.

---

The radio module came assembled, with an antenna which I siliconed so it stands straight up.

Used a [small audio power amplifier](http://www.ebay.com/itm/TDA2030A-Audio-Amplifier-Board-Module-Single-Mono-18W-6-12V-For-Arduino-/282147536160) from eBay (MUCH better than the LM386 audio amplifier module - don't waste your time with them) and mounted it all on a small speaker.

---

Wiring Details:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3wvqd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Arduino Nano mounted on a 140-pin breadboard.  It receives power and programming via the Mini-USB cable, and passes power on to the tuner module and audio amplifier on orange and yellow wires.

**I2C bus to communicate with the tuner is blue and green.  Each is pulled up to `+5V`.**

Audio from the tuner is via a mono 1/8" plug with gray and red wires that go to the amplifier.

[image]

[image: [![enter image description here][3]][]3]

[image]

**Each part was in the dollar-or-two range since I didn't mind waiting for the slow boat.  eBay is definitely where you want to look for the parts for this.**

**This is one of those projects that can be built in an afternoon then used for years.**

---

For reference:

[How to Use the TEA5767 FM Radio Module - Arduino Tutorial (Instructables)](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-the-TEA5767-FM-Radio-module-Arduino-Tut/)

Enjoy!

Comment: If you want more volume at the expensive of more size, here is the amplifier to substitute:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/TDA7297-Version-B-15W-15W-Digital-Audio-Amplifier-Board-Dual-Channel-12V-Hot/132200206508